# Two cases of string concatenation using conditional operator in C++

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation, conditional-operator

The first function works perfectly fine:

```cpp
string createurl(string protocol, string siteName, string domain, bool www = true)
{
    return protocol + "://" + (www ? "www." : "") + siteName + "." + domain;
}
```

But the second one results in a compiler error:

```cpp
string greeting(string name, string gender)
{
    return "Hello " + ((gender == "Male") ? "Mr" : "Miss") + name;
}
```

> Error: C2110 '+': cannot add two pointers.

What is the difference between the two functions to give me this error, and what is the solution?

Comment: `const char* + const char*` is problematic, whereas `std::string + const char*` is ok.

Comment: return std::string("Hello") + ((gender == "Male") ? "Mr" : "Miss") + name;

Comment: first: `operator +`  has an overload that accept a `std::string` and a `const char*`; `protocol` is a `std::string`.
second: a plain string type  has no operator +
fix : `std::string("Hello ") + ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `"Hello " + ((gender == "Male") ? "Mr" : "Miss")` operation tries to concatenate two literal strings, which isn't possible (the literal strings will decay to pointers, and two pointers doesn't make sense).

The quick solution is to make the first string an `std::string` object:

```
using namespace std::literals
// ...
return "Hello "s + ((gender == "Male") ? "Mr" : "Miss") + name;
```

[The trailing `s` in `"Hello "s` turns it into a `std::string` object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).

Comment: but in createurl() function there is a concatenation to 2 string literals "://" and "www." or ""

Comment: @night_ZAK: left associativity, so it is `(protocol + "://") + (www ? "www." : "")`, not `protocol + ("://" + "www.")`.

Answer (score 1):

`"Hello "` is a literal for type `const char[7]`, so it tries to construct a `const char[7]`, which decays into pointer to first element, and add `const char*` to it. Hence the error.

To achieve what you want you can do the following

```
string greeting(string name, string gender)
{
    return string("Hello ") + ((gender == "Male") ? "Mr" : "Miss") + name;
}
```

Because [there is an overload of `operator+` in `std::string` which accepts `const char*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B)

Comment: A C-style string literal is an **array** of `char`. So the type of `"Hello "` is `const char[7]`, not `const char*`. In most contexts the name of an array decays into a pointer to its first element, which is why that array of `char` looks like a pointer. The solution proposed here is correct. +1.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the second function is that none of the operands are `std::string`, they're all string literals. The `+` operator will try to perform addition between two pointers, which is not allowed.

A very simple solution is to make the leftmost operand a `std::string`, just like in the first function:

```cpp
#include <string_view>

// Note: Parameters can be std::string_view.
//       Making them std::string results in unnecessary copying, or creation of strings.
string greeting(string_view name, string_view gender)
{
    return string("Hello ") + (gender == "Male" ? "Mr" : "Miss") + name;
}
```

Alternatively, use functions from the `<format>` header (C++20 required):

```cpp
#include <format>

string greeting(string_view name, string_view gender)
{
    return format("Hello {}. {}", gender == "Male" ? "Mr" : "Mrs", name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is evaluated left to right. This means if you've got a "sum" with more than 1 `+` and no brackets to modify the order, you'll need to make sure at least one of the first 2 summands is a `std::string`. (C++ doesn't allow you to add 2 C string literals using `+`.)

In your case adding a brackets around the last 2 summands would fix the problem, since `char const*` + `std::string` yields a `std::string`:

```
std::string greeting(std::string name, std::string gender)
{
    return "Hello " + (((gender == "Male") ? "Mr" : "Miss") + name);
}
```

In general you'd want to guarantee limit the memory allocations to a minimum, at least for functions that are executed often:

```
std::string greeting(std::string const& name, std::string const& gender)
// passing references to strings can avoid unnecessary copies, if an named string variable is passed
{
    using namespace std::string_view_literals;

    constexpr auto Prefix = "Hello "sv;

    std::string result;

    auto const infix = (gender == "Male") ? "Mr"sv : "Miss"sv;

    result.reserve(Prefix.size() + name.size() + infix.size()); // allocate enough memory to store everything in one go
    result.assign(Prefix).append(infix).append(name); // compose the resulting string in the already allocated memory

    return result;
}
```